# Can anyone explain why the address of a pointer change when called by another function? How to make nPtr=Ptr?

Tags: c

I noticed that my pointer address is different when it is passed to a function. U am not sure to 
 access the value that exists inside the function? Please don't suggest returning the pointer 
 value from the function. I strictly want to use void function. 

output: 
&nPtr = 6422300  
&Ptr = 6422272 
&nPtr = 6422300 

See the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void myFunc(int *Ptr){
    printf("&Ptr = %d\n", &Ptr);
};

void main(){
    int *nPtr;
    printf("&nPtr = %d\n", &nPtr);
    myFunc(nPtr);
    printf("&nPtr = %d\n", &nPtr);
}
```

Let me be more clear. Here is the code that I am trying to fix. All what I 
 want is to make the two pointers point to the same address. I want to 
 use the best coding practice.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void myFunc(int *Ptr){
    Ptr = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    printf("*Ptr = %d\n", *Ptr);
};

void main(){
    
    int *nPtr;
    printf("*nPtr = %d\n", *nPtr);
    
    myFunc(nPtr);
    printf("*nPtr = %d\n", *nPtr);

}
```

Comment: myFunc uses *Ptr, while main uses int *nPtr.
try int *Ptr in main.
nptr is a pointer to the next node

Comment: How to make nPtr=Ptr?

Comment: Do you want to make `nPtr==Ptr` or do you want to make `&nPtr==&nPtr`? These are two completely different things. The latter is impossible because those are two different variables, and each variable must have its own address. The former you already have, but you are printing `&Ptr` in the function, not `Ptr`. If you printed `Ptr` it would be the same as `nPtr`, but it would _not_ be the same as `&nPtr`, which you are printing out in `main()`.

Comment: P.S. You should use `%p` format specifier to printf pointers. Not all pointers are `int`s, some are longer.

Answer (score 1):

`nPtr` and `Ptr` are separate variables in separate functions, and as such each must necessarily have a different address, i.e. `&nPtr == &Ptr` will always be false.

But you asked about `nPtr == Ptr`, i.e. can they contain the same *value*, and as pointers they can both contain the same pointer value.  For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void myFunc(int *Ptr){
    printf("Ptr = %p\n", (void *)Ptr);
};

int main(){
    int x;
    int *nPtr = &x;
    printf("nPtr = %p\n", (void *)nPtr);
    myFunc(nPtr);
    printf("nPtr = %p\n", (void *)nPtr);
}
```

Output:

```
nPtr = 0x7ffe9a615104
Ptr = 0x7ffe9a615104
nPtr = 0x7ffe9a615104
```

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, you're getting the address of `nPtr` in `main()`'s stack frame; in `myFunc()`, you're getting the address of the copy of `nPtr` that is being passed by value to `myFunc()` as `Ptr` (so you're actually getting the address of `Ptr`, which is distinct) and exists on `myFunc()`'s stack frame.

Comment: How to make nPtr=Ptr?

Answer (score 0):

For this function

```
void myFunc(int *Ptr){
    printf("&Ptr = %d\n", &Ptr);
};
```

when you call it, although you are passing a pointer (which is for pointing to an integer) to this function , the system is creating a copy of the pointer and of course they will be at different memory address.

Hence when you return back to the main and retrieve your original pointer address, it will be displaying back the original address